# Is this valid JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"something":"1","mode":"true","number":"1234"}
```

Because I'm getting a 406 on expecting JSON.

It's being generated via Jersey, which is told that a method @Produces JSON. It's being received by a Dojo xhrGet which has JSON set as its handleAs.

EDIT - To clarify, I'm not interested in the code where I evaluate or anything like that. The question was very simple - is it valid JSON?

Comment: share the code where you evaluate it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is, but you've got both the boolean (`mode`) and numeric (`number`) elements as strings. Shouldn't it be:

```
{"something":"1","mode":true,"number":1234}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is valid JSON if all values of the dictionary are Strings. This is also valid JSON:

{"something": 1, "mode": true, "number": 1234}

Usually, however, a 406 error happens when you ask for a response type (such as html or json) and the server cannot send it in that type.  Why do you think the input is invalid?

Answer (score 6):

I use a simple copy/paste tool called JASONLint ( http://www.jsonlint.com/ ) to test my mountains of JSON.  You may dig it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the numbers directly, you shouldn't put them in quotes. It is valid JSON, but chances are that what you want to do is:

{"something":1,"mode":"true","number":1234}

You need to add more information if you want better answers.

EDIT: Eh... and yes, the boolean shouldn't be quoted either, unless you *want* to convert it yourself, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

- yes this is valid JSON
- although if you're planning on outputting this as the result of a HTTP request, you'll need to escape all the quotes

$str = "{\"something\":\"1\",\"mode\":\"true\",\"number\":\"1234\"}";
echo $str